# How can we limit the gesture property in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii ,i am doing a reader application which have chapters in it,i have done the swipe recognition property in tableview for reloading tableview with next and previous chapters right-swipe for next and left swipe for previous.And at the same time i added button for same function in button click,the problem is when the chapter ends that means the book containing only 9 chapters and if i reach the 9th chapter the swipe propert for right have to be stopped and vice versa.But i have done it in button by disabling the button if the chapter 9 loda it atomatically disabled the button so the user didnt tap the button,i want this same methode in my swipe right and left function>how to do this this is my code for swipe

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; // or whatever
    [table addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
    [swipeGesture release];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureleft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureleft:)];
    swipeGestureleft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft; // or whatever
    [table addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureleft];
    [swipeGestureleft release];
-(void) handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
    [delegate reloadVerses];
    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1]; 
}
```

EDIT:::
    -(void) handleSwipeGestureleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

```
    delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] - 1];
    [delegate reloadVerses];
    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1]; 
}
```

this is the method where i hides the button or disabled the button here i want to stop and start the gesture.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.
Thanks in advance.
edit

```
-(void)resetReadViewToVerse:(int)verseNo;
{
    if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        previousButton.enabled = YES; 
        table.tableHeaderView =previousButton;


    }
    else
    {
        previousButton.enabled = NO;
        table.tableHeaderView =nil;

    }

    if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[DbHandler mNumberOfChaptersInBook:delegate.selectedBook]]])
    {
        nextButton.enabled =YES;
        table.tableFooterView =nextButton;


    }
    else
    {
        nextButton.enabled = NO;
        table.tableFooterView =nil;

    }
    -(void) handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {


     if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[DbHandler mNumberOfChaptersInBook:delegate.selectedBook]]]) {
        // if the currentChapter is the last then do nothing
         delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
         [delegate reloadVerses];
         [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
    }
    return;



}
-(void) handleSwipeGestureleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    if(![delegate.selectedChapter isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] - 1];
        [delegate reloadVerses];
        [self resetReadViewToVerse:1]; 
    }
    return;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to deactivate the gesture you just need to check that the selectedChapter + 1 is not more than the total number of chapters, if it is you ignore the gesture.

EDIT:

You can do something like this (assuming you can ask the delegate totalNumberOfChapters):

```
-(void) handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    // delegate.selectedChapter should be NSInteger, would be easier

    NSInteger currentChapter = [delegate.selectedChapter integerValue];

    if (currentChapter >= delegate.totalNumberOfChapters) {
        // if the currentChapter is the last then do nothing
        return;
    }

    delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
    [delegate reloadVerses];
    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1]; 
}
```

Comment: thanks again for your kind response but where did i put the condition please see my edit in my question.this is where i put condition to enable and disable the button for next chapter and prv chapter.

Comment: sir my Offic time over, tmaro mrng I will chk the code thanks verymuch